# Create Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray from another array with different structure

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have first `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "Fields": [
      {
        "Value": "child",
        "Key": "Relationship"
      },
      {
        "Value": "Alex",
        "Key": "FirstName"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And another `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`:

```
[
  {
    "Relationship": "child",
    "FirstName": "Alex"
  }
]
```

Is it real to turn second one to the first one? Have not much experience in c# and Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform your first JSON sample to your second, you may use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm) as follows:

```
// Parse (or load from a stream) the incoming JSON as a JArray
var array = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

// For each object in the array, query they Key/Value properties of each Fields[*] object and turn then into a single JPropery, 
// then add those properties to a new JObject
var query = array.Select(i => 
    new JObject(i.SelectTokens("Fields[*]").Select(o => new JProperty((string)o["Key"], o["Value"]))));

// Create a new JArray from the query
var newArray = new JArray(query);
```

The trickest part is here:

```
i => new JObject(i.SelectTokens("Fields[*]").Select(o => 
    new JProperty((string)o["Key"], o["Value"])))
```

This expression:

1. Uses [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) to query all `Fields[*]` objects in the root array item;
2. then gets the `"Key"` and `"Value"` properties of each object;
3. then turns them into a single [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jproperty.htm);
4. and finally combines the `JProperty` instances into a single [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

Note that, if one of the `[*].Fields[*].Key` properties is missing, the code above will throw an exception, so you might want to check for that.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8qbDmX).

Similarly, to transform your second sample to your first, you can do:

```
var query = array
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Select(o => 
           new JObject
           {
               {"Fields", new JArray(o.Properties().Select(p => new JObject{{"Key", p.Name}, {"Value", p.Value}}))},
           });

var newArray = new JArray(query);
```

Here I am using C#'s [dictionary collection initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) to initialize my `JObject` instances, which I can do because `JObject` implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPYJkb).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brilliant answer.  Actually I asked to turn the second array into the first one, but even your example is enough for me to do it myself. Thanks again

Comment: @NickANV - updated to add reverse transform.